# jquery mobile: scrolling to the bottom of the page. issues with iOS 5

Tags: jquery, ios5, jquery-mobile, scroll

I have a mobile chat window I made in jQM 1.0.1. It works fine for everything except scrolling to the bottom when new text comes in on iOS 5 specifically (guessing because of touchOverflow being enabled).

I basically have a fixed header and footer, and a content div that I append()

tags with the text to as it comes in (from periodic polling for new lines). Real simple. When I get new text, I do the following after appending it to the div:

```
  var contentDiv = $('.chatHistory', thisPage);
  contentDiv.trigger('updatelayout');

  $(document).scrollTop(10000000);
  //NOTE: $(window).scrollTop(10000000); works too
```

This works well (on Android ICS for instance) to scroll down so that the new content shows up at the bottom of the page. (There's some whitespace that appears for a sec as the updatelayout completes, but past that it's functional). On iOS (v5 at least), I can't for the life of me get this kind of thing to work.

Do I need to use a scrollView? (I'd like to avoid it if possible so this works with as many platforms as JQM supports.) Is there another method for scrolling with touchOverflow?

Thanks!

Comment: For me was usefull this http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: Have you tried applying scrollTop to html and/or body element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the docs for JQM 1.2, any luck with `$.mobile.silentScroll(1000000)` ?
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html

I'd probably suggest:
`$.mobile.silentScroll($(document).height())`

Not sure if all browsers would support going over the height of the object.